# SQL sum calc returning multiple of same rows in stead of single sum

Tags: sql-server

I have the following sql query,i only want the total sum of a column but its returing multiple of the same records as follows

```
SELECT 
        b.[Name] 

        sum(td.detailNumber) over () as Totaldetail,
        sum(t.Original) over () as TotalOriginal
    FROM Detail td WITH(NOLOCK)
        inner JOIN Ticket t WITH(NOLOCK) ON t.ID = td.ID
        inner JOIN [system].Branch b WITH(NOLOCK) ON t.BranchID = b.BranchID
        inner JOIN Option mo WITH(NOLOCK) ON OptionID = td.MID

    WHERE (td.ResultDateTime >= '2018/03/10 00:00:00:000' AND td.ResultDateTime <= '2018/03/10 23:59:59:000')
        AND t.BranchID IN (SELECT Data FROM [system].Split('37', ','))

        AND t.Code IN ('RS','AC')
```

results given

```
Totaldetail | Totaloriginal
54868       | 78569
54868       | 78569
54868       | 78569
54868       | 78569
54868       | 78569
54868       | 78569
54868       | 78569
```

as you can see above its showing me multiple rows for the date i provided.i only want one result at a time example

```
Totaldetail | Totaloriginal
    54868   | 78569       //only one record to be shown
```

Comment: `GROUP BY B.Name`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, delete you `OVER` clauses. The `OVER()` clause makes your `SUM` a windowed function, so it doesn't group anything. This is why you were seeing the rows without grouping.

If you want to see aggregates by each name then add `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT 
    b.[Name],
    sum(td.detailNumber) as Totaldetail,
    sum(t.Original) as TotalOriginal
FROM Detail td WITH(NOLOCK)
    inner JOIN Ticket t WITH(NOLOCK) ON t.ID = td.ID
    inner JOIN [system].Branch b WITH(NOLOCK) ON t.BranchID = b.BranchID
    inner JOIN Option mo WITH(NOLOCK) ON OptionID = td.MID

WHERE (td.ResultDateTime >= '2018/03/10 00:00:00:000' AND td.ResultDateTime <= '2018/03/10 23:59:59:000')
    AND t.BranchID IN (SELECT Data FROM [system].Split('37', ','))
    AND t.Code IN ('RS','AC')
GROUP BY
     b.[Name]
```

If you just want to see totals, remove the b.[name] column.

```
SELECT 
    sum(td.detailNumber) as Totaldetail,
    sum(t.Original) as TotalOriginal
FROM Detail td WITH(NOLOCK)
    inner JOIN Ticket t WITH(NOLOCK) ON t.ID = td.ID
    inner JOIN [system].Branch b WITH(NOLOCK) ON t.BranchID = b.BranchID
    inner JOIN Option mo WITH(NOLOCK) ON OptionID = td.MID

WHERE (td.ResultDateTime >= '2018/03/10 00:00:00:000' AND td.ResultDateTime <= '2018/03/10 23:59:59:000')
    AND t.BranchID IN (SELECT Data FROM [system].Split('37', ','))
    AND t.Code IN ('RS','AC')
```